# jQuery / JavaScript - Trigger hover on a element when mouse over on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, mouseover

Is this possible? My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li> <a> link </a> </li>
  <li> <a> link </a> </li>
  <li> <a> link </a> 
    <ul>
      <li> <a> sub-link </a> </li>  
      <li> <a> sub-link </a> </li>  
      <li> <a> sub-link </a> </li>  
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Basically I want to trigger the hover CSS rule on the parent menu link when the mouse is over a child menu link.

Comment: a solution to this would be to move the hover styles on the `<li>` element, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to have :hover on li's instead of a's...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) it'll affect the parent as well, since that's how the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events work, for example:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6ncQR/), unlike `mouseover` and `mouseout`, the events *don't* fire when entering/leaving children, so the action taken on the parent isn't "undone" until you actually leave the parent as well, which seems to be what you're after.

Or, use pure CSS if you're just doing styling, like this (doesn't work in IE6):

```
li:hover > a { color: red; }​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6ncQR/1/).

Comment: Hi. I know, but I'm not talking about enabling mouse over events, I just want the :hover style to be applied to the parent link, even if the mouse is not over it.

Comment: @Alex - If you put the `:hover` on the `<li>` you can do it, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6ncQR/1/

Comment: oh nvm :D
tx, i'll use li:hover

Comment: @Alex - Make sure you have the CSS like it is on the right in the demo...of you had an example page I could take a look.

Comment: thank you, actually all that i need was the ">" css thing. didnt knew about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the parent node by using parent() method and toggle its class binding the mouseover and mouseout events.

```
$("#childnode").bind("mouseover", function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("onmouseover");
}).bind("mouseout", function() {
   $(this).parent().removeClass("onmouseover");
});
```